# SFINAE template constructor with boost::hana

Tags: c++, boost, boost-hana

Given the following code, what is an appropriate way to express the same functionality with Boost hana?

```
#include <type_traits>

#include <boost/hana/type.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/core/when.hpp>
namespace hana = boost::hana;

struct S {
    template<
        typename T,
        typename = typename std::enable_if_t< (T::value) > > // <-- equivalent?
    S (const T&) { }
};

struct X { static constexpr int value = 0; };
struct Y { static constexpr int value = 1; };

int main () {
    S a (X { }); // <-- must fail
    S b (Y { });
    return 0;
}
```

The doc for `when` mention it as a replacement for `enable_if` but I am not sure how to apply it in this context. So, how do I selectively enable a template constructor with Boost hana?

Comment: `hana::when` is about enabling partial specializations.

Comment: @Barry: Right, what I am looking for is a (perhaps) clever way to replace the plain enable_if with some succinct hana incantation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Barry says in the comments, `hana::when` is useful for partial specializations, and it can't be used in your case. Hana does not provide an incantation that is more succinct than what you already have (which is fair given it's a one liner). Also note that you may drop the extra `typename` keyword in from of `std::enable_if_t`.